# LNK 2001 : unresolved external symbol while initializing static member

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to implement a vitual Keyboard class for that I am having different keyboard layouts as shown.

KeyBoard.hpp

```
 class CKeyBoard 
 {
    public:

    enum eKeyBoardLayout
    {
        UPPER_CASE_ALPHABETS,
        LOWER_CASE_ALPHABETS,
        UPPER_CASE_NUMBERS,
        LOWER_CASE_NUMBERS,
        MAX_KEYBOARDLAYOUTS,
    };
    CKeyBoard();
    void hideCharacters(bool hide); // for password
    void setDisplayBufferLength(UNSIGNED8_T maxCharToDisplay);
    virtual ~CKeyBoard();
    static const UNSIGNED8_T const_noOfRows = 0x03; // 3 rows for character keys
    struct SLayout
    {
        UNSIGNED8_T noOfColumns[const_noOfRows];    ///< noofcolumns in each row may be different
        TypedText     textAreaFont; 
        const KeyMapping* pKeyMapping;
    };
    static const SLayout m_KeyBoardLayouts[MAX_KEYBOARDLAYOUTS];
private:
    /*methods*/
    void setKeyBoardLayout(eKeyBoardLayout);
    void backspacePressedHndlr();
    void letterCasePressedHndlr();
    void alphabetNumberToggleHndlr();
    /*members*/
    static const UNSIGNED8_T const_maxNoOfKeysSupprtd = 26;
    CKey m_keyArray[const_maxNoOfKeysSupprtd]; 
    CMenuItem m_KeySpaceBar;
    CMenuToggle m_KeyCaseSwitch;
    CMenuToggle m_KeyAlphaNum;
    CMenuItem m_keyBackSpace;
    eKeyBoardLayout m_eCurrentKeyLayout;
    CKeyBoardDisplayArea m_DisplayArea;
```

};

I am initialising the static member as follows in cpp file.
KeyBoard.cpp

```
static const CKeyBoard::SLayout   m_KeyBoardLayouts[CKeyBoard::MAX_KEYBOARDLAYOUTS] = \
  {
      //      UPPER_CASE_ALPHABETS,
    {
      { 10, 9, 7 },
        TypedText(T_KEYBOARD),
        &keyMappingsAlphaUpper[0],

},
//      LOWER_CASE_ALPHABETS,
{
    { 10, 9, 7 },
    TypedText(T_KEYBOARD),
    &keyMappingsAlphaLower[0],
},
//      UPPER_CASE_NUMBERS,
{
    { 10, 10, 5 },
    TypedText(T_KEYBOARD),
    &keyMappingsNumLower[0],
},
//      LOWER_CASE_NUMBERS,
{
    { 10, 10, 5 },
    TypedText(T_KEYBOARD),
    &keyMappingsNumLower[0]
},


};
// Other function definitions
CKey::CKey() : m_pCallback(NULL)
{
}
```

But still I am getting unresolved external symbol as linker error. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Error Details:
*
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct CKeyBoard::SLayout const * const CKeyBoard::m_KeyBoardLayouts" (?m_KeyBoardLayouts@CKeyBoard@@2QBUSLayout@1@B) 
*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the class scope:

```
static const CKeyBoard::SLayout   
    CKeyBoard::m_KeyBoardLayouts[CKeyBoard::MAX_KEYBOARDLAYOUTS]
```

It's actually a pity the compiler doesn't warn about static linkage like that...  It's a common mistake.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for pointing that out.. 
But when I made the edit another strange error popped-up.

error C2720: 'CKeyBoard::m_KeyBoardLayouts' : 'static ' storage-class specifier illegal on members keyboard.cpp 
And It was solved by initializing as follows. CKeyBoard::SLayout const CKeyBoard::m_KeyBoardLayouts[CKeyBoard::MAX_KEYBOARDLAYOUTS]

Comment: Why is this happening? (I am aware that initialization which i did is wrong)

Comment: That's C++ :).  You _declare_ it `static`, but you just _define_ the symbol.  (You don't add `public` before your definitions, do you?  Read up here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static